# JavaScript sort array of objects based on an array of values

Tags: javascript

I need to sort my `list` using the `selected` array.

```js
const list = [
    { name: 'BMW' },
    { name: 'AUDI' },
    { name: 'MINI' },
    { name: 'FIAT' },
    { name: 'KIA' },
]

const selected = [ 'MINI', 'KIA' ]
```

What is the best way to do this? I have found some examples but not too sure how to adapt this to work the way I want it to!

```js
list.sort((a,b) => (a.last_nom > b.last_nom) ? 1 : ((b.last_nom > a.last_nom) ? -1 : 0))
```

### Expected result:

```js
const list = [
    { name: 'MINI' },
    { name: 'KIA' },
    { name: 'BMW' },
    { name: 'AUDI' },
    { name: 'FIAT' },
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `last_nom` be `name`?

Comment: Use `selected.indexOf(a.name)` and `selected.indexOf(b.name)`, and compare those before comparing the values of `a.name` and `b.name`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an object array by custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028512/sort-an-object-array-by-custom-order)

Comment: @stevecomrie That's not quite the same, because the custom order there includes all the names. `selected` just has some ofthem.

Comment: Does the order within the selected and non-selected groups matter?

Comment: @Barmar - that's a bit of a distinction without a difference

Comment: @stevecomrie If you use the solution that assumes they're all included, the non-matching items will be sorted ahead of the matching items because `indexOf()` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and take advantage of JavaScript's numbers [coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) like this:

```js
const list = [
  { name: "BMW" },
  { name: "AUDI" },
  { name: "MINI" },
  { name: "FIAT" },
  { name: "KIA" },
];

const selected = ["MINI", "KIA"];

const sorted = list.sort(
  (a, b) => selected.includes(b.name) - selected.includes(a.name)
);

console.log(sorted);
```

If the order of the elements has to remain the same and be consistent across browsers:

```js
const list = [
  { name: "BMW" },
  { name: "AUDI" },
  { name: "MINI" },
  { name: "FIAT" },
  { name: "KIA" },
];

const selected = ["MINI", "KIA"];

const sorted = list.sort(
  (a, b) =>
    selected.includes(b.name) - selected.includes(a.name) ||
    list.indexOf(a) - list.indexOf(b)
);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: `includes()` just returns true or false, it doesn't really make sense to subtract them.

Comment: Still it returns a number that represents the difference as if `true` were `1` and `false` were `0`

Comment: I assumed that if both are in selected, they want them in the same order as in `selected`. This puts all the selected items first, non-selected items later, but doesn't specify the order within those groups.

Comment: Indeed, chromium happens to preserve the order but it's implementation-dependent

Comment: Yeah as long as the selected are at the top that's all I need :D